# Missing cloud messaging permission though I am not using Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, firebase

I am using Firebase Crash Reporting and Firebase Remote Config, but I am not using Firebase Cloud Messaging. Version of both is 9.8.0.

So, I don't understand why am I seeing this error in logs:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms (has extras) } without permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1266)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1243)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:588)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.zzf.zzb(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.zzf.zza(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.zzf.zzb(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.zzf.zza(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzc(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.getToken(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getToken(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zzaae(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zza(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService.zzm(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$2.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Could it be, because I am depending on Google Cloud Messaging (but not using - library dependency - internal company library)?

Does it have any serious consequences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Doug Stevenson in [this groups post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/CXgecSxgsRE/84PsoyTKGgAJ), the RECEIVE, C2D_MESSAGE, and WAKE_LOCK permissions are required by Analytics, Crash Reporting, and Remote Config.

The primary use is to generate secure tokens and, in the case of WAKE_LOCK, to prevent data loss, by keeping Android from killing the app's process before it's able to transmit collected data.